# Why is fullName not displaying name after space

Tags: c++, string

The final cout is not displaying the cin `fullName`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string fullName;
    cout << "Type your full name: ";
    cin >> fullName;
    cout << "Your name is: " << fullName; //this final cout is not displaying the cin fullName
    system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: Did you provide any input?

Comment: Yes, if the name inputted is "Rob King", it would only output Rob

Comment: @OMGItsRob You should add that information to the question. As it stands, the question makes it look like the final `cout` statement is not displaying *any* of the full name. A better question would specify the input, expected output, and actual output. It would also have more text describing the problem, so that the question looks like more than just a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin` does not work with spaces in the input, the rest of your input is in the buffer.
Try using `getline` like this:

```
 int main()
{
    string fullName;
    cout << "Type your full name:" ;
    getline(cin,fullName);
    cout << "Your name is: " << fullName; 
    system("pause>0");
}
```

This way it will save into your variable everything until it hits a `\n`.